# Row locking in MySql InnoDb with foreign key constraints and indexes applied?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

Quick question.

Talking to my friend with 25 years db experience he was telling me if you use foreign key constraints in a db; when a table is being written to for example, a table for messages, it will lock out the relative row on the parent table for say, users.

Is this true?

Also he said that applying indexes to the Foreign Key Columns should overcome this locking out, is this true?

I am concerned as my website traffic is growing and I can imagine this being an issue!

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot say anything for the parent-table locking, but I know that indexing your foreign key columns is a bright idea.  Especially since you probably use those keys for joins.  Doing this can increase your query performance by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Using joins should still be done with care (only when needed) in cluster server, you can end up with full table scans that really hurt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on this - http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/09/20/instrumentation-and-the-cost-of-foreign-keys/ - the demo is just as your friend described.  There is locking on parent rows!

Now for the part about explaining the difference between an "index" and a "key":

- A key is like some high level relational property.  This matches that.
- An index is an implementation detail.

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), "InnoDB requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.".  That is, if you don't add an index when you add your foreign key, InnoDB will automatically.

No amount of indexing prevents the parent locking described in my blog post.

Comment: @morgan-tocker could the locks be mitigated by creating tables whose sole purpose is to provide an up to date list of primary keys that the child has FKs for?

For example: table C has two children (A & E).  My idea is to create two single column tables (B & D) that contain a foreign key to C (kept up to date with triggers on C).

If A/E foreign key to B/D instead of C would that prevent one from being able to lock the other but keep the value of foreign key constraints?

Comment: Locking can be reduced with normalization in general; since the smallest granularity of locks is at the row level.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/12/12/innodb-locking-and-foreign-keys/

Comment: Thanks for that, I was reading this earlier. It gives me a better understanding but doesn't directly answer the question I don't think as my friend is a DB expert so wanted to get a personal opinion on the matter AND wether there was a solution?